# Android: Multiple Views on a Activity

Tags: android, multithreading, layout, surfaceview

Here is my main:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
    TextView text=  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("This is a Test!");

    firstCircle first = new firstCircle(this);
    secondCircle second = new secondCircle(this);
    layout.addView(first);
    layout.addView(second);

}
```

Here is my firstCircleClass:

```
public class firstCircle extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private firstThread _firstThread;
private secondThread _secondThread;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;


public firstCircle (Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context,attrs);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    _firstThread= new firstThread(getHolder(),this);

}

public firstCircle (Context context){
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    _firstThread= new firstThread(getHolder(),this);

}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c){

    String tag="My Activity";
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

      c.drawCircle(100,100,100,paint);

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    _firstThread.setRunning(true);
    _firstThread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
    boolean retry = true;
    _firstThread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry){
        try{
            _firstThread.join();
            retry = false;
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}




}
```

I have a secondCircle class that is the exact same as above with the name changed and the color of the circle being Red.

Here is my firstThread class:

```
public class firstThread extends Thread {

private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
private firstClass _firstClass;
private boolean _run = false;

public firstThread (SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, firstClass first){
    _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    _firstClass= first;

}


public void setRunning (boolean run){
    _run = run;
}

@Override
public void run(){

    while(_run){
        Canvas c=null;
        try{
            c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized(_surfaceHolder){
                    _firstThread.onDraw(c);
            }


        } finally {
        }
            if (c!=null){
                _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have a secondThread class that is the same as above with a different name and that calls secondCircle's onDraw().

When i run this program it only shows the blue circle and not the red circle. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you add the views, add them with layout parameters.  Its possible the 1st view is filling the parent, leaving no space for the second view.

you could do something like

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.addView(first,p);
    layout.addView(second,p);
```

Comment: Thx for the input. I tried the above and i can still only see the blue circle. Any other ideas? Also if i choose to comment out layout.addView(first) then the red circle appears

Comment: maybe the content is still too big even if wrapping.  try setting it as a test with new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50) instead of wrap_content.  also - the parent linear layout - is that vertical or horizntal?  what are its settings - is it set to fill_parent?

Comment: i tried it as high as (500,500) and it still doesn't work. The parent linear layout is vertical and is set to fill_parent. Do you suppose that once the firstCircle is drawn and the thread is running it is blocking the secondThread from running?

Comment: dont set it high, set it low - ie make them small so they might fit.  I doubt its blocking but just throw a logcat line in the threads to see if they are firing like public void run(){ Log.d("Test","Running"); ...

Comment: Doing (50,50) clipped the image to a small quarter of a blue circle but still no red circle. I added a logcat and looks like both threads are running. Any other ideas?

Comment: interestingly enough when i take out the LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50); line then it doesnt look like the second thread runs

Comment: ahh ok, when i set it to (300,300) i can see the blue circle and a little bit of the red circle so you were right! But the red circle is really low almost off screen why is this?

Comment: I should say how can i fit both views on the screen?

Comment: ok - i haven't played with surfaceviews but i think the issue is the canvas is coming from the size of the parent view -in this case your wrapper linearlayout.  Try adding two child Layouts inside the wrapper, and put one circle in one, and the other in the other.  set the size of each of the child layouts to start to ensure they fit and see if thats the problem.